# Get UUID without iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, uuid

I am looking for a way to extract my iPhone (OS v3.0) UUID without using iTunes. I tried "UUID Revealer" from Cydia Store but that is not working on my system. I could SSH with WinSCP and I have a Terminal Program Installed. Any chances using one of those tools (or another one) to bring to light my UUID? Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your development environment? Sounds like you do doing things "non-standard".

Answer (score 42):

1. Connect your iPhone to the Mac(mine is OS10.8).
2. Launch System Information under Utilies
3. the UUID of your iPhone is list under USB/iPhone/Serial Number

Comment: This is a good solution for the Mac, especially since the UUID is cut-and-paste-able.

Comment: Serial Number is NOT THE SAME as UUID. Wrong answer.

Comment: BartłomiejSemańczyk, it is actually the same as the UDID. I confirmed by comparing against the UDID in iTunes. Ray's answer is correct.

Comment: The Serial number IS NOT the same as UUID. To see the UUID you need to follow the steps 1-2-3 that @Ray said and click on Serial-Number, after that the UUID will appear

Comment: I think one point of confusion is terminology. On my machine, the _Serial Number_ in System Information is the same as _UUID_ of the device in XCode (Devices view). **However**, in XCode the _Serial Number_ is a different piece of information from the _UUID_

Comment: Note that when entering this value into the developer area to provision a new device, you need a hyphen after the first 8 digits.

Answer (score 38):

On an apt-compatible Linux use:

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils
```

Now you can do

```
idevice_id -l
```

to get the device UUID while it's connected by USB.

Comment: This works even in 2017 (cox you can't be sure as Apple makes restrictions tighter every year.)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - simple and straightforward. +1

Comment: Works fine in 2020, should be top answer!

Comment: This works fine in 2021. Easy way to get UDID

Answer (score 28):

This is super easy on Windows. 
You can also go to Control Panel > Devices and printers in win 7.
Plug in the phone

```
Device Manager > Iphone 
Right - click
Properties > Hardware Tab
Properties > Details Tab
Property > Device Instance Path
```

UUID is the last device path listed.

```
USB\VID_05AC&PID_1297\UUID String
```

Enjoy skipping itunes installation.

Comment: On Win10 (without iTunes installed) I just see this:

USB\VID_05AC&PID_12A8&MI_00\0

The UUID isn't anywhere to be seen

Comment: Worked on Win10 but instead in Device Manger it was under "Portable Devices"

Then
Properties -> Details -> Device Instance path

Answer (score 9):

There are probably 20 "UUID Display" apps in the app store.  I think the best thing to do is to try a few and see what works for you.  Like almost everything else in the App Store, the apps to show UUID is saturated.

HI just tried a **free** app  (I have no affiliation with this app) and it worked on my 3G.

[ShareAbout - Share Device ID on iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shareabout-share-device-id/id305722260?mt=8)

Answer (score 4):

Just go to `Finder`, find your device. Trust it, click `xx.xxGB` and it will switch among `uuid`、`ime` and `xxx.GB`. Right click the content and copy it. Done :)

Comment: This one is easiest and simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this by opening up XCode.  The device will have a label called "Identifier".  This is your UUID.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [iStat](http://bjango.com/apps/istat/) (99¢) from [Bjango](http://bjango.com/apps/) or you could plug your iPhone into your computer, and open the Organizer (Window » Organizer) and it will show it there). Or you could take @wkw's idea to do it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

open cydia and at the bottom on the homescreen you'll find the UUID. no need for windows either

Answer (score 1):

On VMWare:

1. open the VMWare-Logs (On Linux: in your VMWare Directory, vmware.log).
2. Plugin your Iphone and connect it in VMware as USB-Device
3. Search in the logs for: "USB: Device [name:Apple". In this Line, you find *serialnum:*. This is the UUID you"re searching for.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, connect your iOS device to Linux/Unix machine, and then run this simple Linux command to get UDID:

```
lsusb -s `lsusb | grep "Apple" | cut -d ' ' -f 2`:`lsusb | grep "Apple" | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed 's/://'` -v | grep iSerial | awk '{print $3}'
```

or for some Linux distros, use this:

```
lsusb -s :`lsusb | grep iPhone | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed 's/://'` -v | grep iSerial | awk '{print $3}'
```