# Building an iOS signing key for PhoneGap in Windows

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, cordova, phonegap-build

Recently I've been asked by a number of developers how they can use PhoneGapBuild (PGB) to develop an iOS app when they only have a windows machine? The problem not being the development itself, but the provision of a key that PGB can use to build the iOS app.

One major problem is that PGB's faq gives instructions for using a mac to achieve this, and another being that Apple's documentation assumes the same.

So, can a key be created in windows without the use of a mac, and if so, what are the exact steps to do so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I always send people a link to an excellent article by Ian Devlin: http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows.

The core of the solution is to do the following in windows using either windows openssl, or the cygwin variant:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ios.key 2048

openssl req -new -key ios.key -out ios.csr -subj "/emailAddress=MY-EMAIL-ADDRESS, CN=COMPANY-NAME, C=COUNTRY-CODE"
```

Then, go to [apple](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) to request a cert, using the csr file you've just generated. This is pretty easy.

Generate a PEM and P12:

```
openssl x509 -in ios_development.cer -inform DER -out ios_development.pem -outform PEM

openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ios.key -in ios_development.pem -out ios_development.p12
```

The end of Ian's explanation says,

> The last file you need to generate is the provisioning profile, which
>   again requires you to return to the Apple Provisioning Portal. There
>   is plenty of documentation there on how to do this, so I won’t go into
>   it here. Bear in mind that such certificates need to be tied to your
>   iOS testing devices via their UDIDs, and again there is documentation
>   on how to do this.
>
> Once the provisioning profile is generated, download it (e.g.
>   iOS_Development.mobileprovision) and save it in the same place as the
>   other files. This file will also need to be installed on each of your
>   iOS testing devices.

During the provisioning process you'll have to create a bundle id -- don't try to find it because it doesn't exist -- you are meant to make it up, and the easiest way is to use a wildcard id like com.yourcompany.*. If you're not using an ad-hoc distribution, which is recommended, you'll also be asked for the UUID for your iOS device. You can download a UUID app for free that will give you this, or you can just plug the device into windows and find the data in itunes (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697049/get-uuid-without-itunes)). The app approach is preferable if you don't like itunes (and let's face it, if you're reading this then you probably don't).

Finally, you don't need to upload the provisioning file to your iOS device. You can use almost any QR Code scanner to load it and both the app and provisioning file will be installed.

Comment: As the article says, annoyingly you still need a Mac to upload anything to the app store though. Bah Apple.

Comment: How to request a cert in apple's website? When I try it, I can't find certification request menu. Should I pay $99 for apple developer program enrollment to see certification request menu? @IanDevlin

Comment: I'm not an expert on all things Apple, but yeah, I think the world's richest company is charging developers to write code for their platform. If you have a choice, don't pay it -- it's obscene.

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://www.macincloud.com/ for rent-a-mac by the hour. Preinstalled with Application Loader too, this is what I use to upload my apps built by PhoneGap Build. Easy enough even though you'd really think Apple would provide another option by now.

Comment: This is 2020 and you still need a Mac to upload your app to the App Store. Thanks Apple :(